# How to write this as an SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a code that is written in php and its a query, but i want to convert in into sql query

```
return TimetableEntry::select('timetable_entries.id as tid')

    ->addSelect('timetable_entries.id as tid')

    ->join('weekdays', 'timetable_entries.weekday_id', '=', 'weekdays.id')

    ->addSelect('weekdays.weekday as tweek')

    ->join('employees', 'timetable_entries.employee_id', '=', 'employees.id')

    ->addSelect('employees.id as eid')

    ->join('users', 'users.username', '=', 'employees.employee_number')

    ->join('timetables', 'timetables.id', '=', timetable_entries.timetable_id')

    ->addSelect('timetables.start_date as tstart')

    ->addSelect('timetables.end_date as tend')

    ->join('class_timings', 'class_timings.id', '=','timetable_entries.class_timing_id')

    ->addSelect('class_timings.start_time as start')

    ->where('users.id','=',$this->id)

    ->get();
```

Comment: Do you have a specific problem or are you asking someone to write the query for you? Can you post any attempts you've already made?

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: sorry for unclarification, but its the first time for me, I tried to write the basic sql statements but iam not sure about my query.

Answer (score 0):

Query can Looks Like

```
select timetable_entries.id as tid ,
weekdays.weekday as tweek,
employees.id as eid,
timetables.start_date as tstart,
timetables.end_date as tend,
class_timings.start_time as start

From timetable_entries
join weekdays
ON
timetable_entries.weekday_id=weekdays.id

join employees
ON 
timetable_entries.employee_id=employees.id

join users
ON users.username=employees.employee_number

join timetables
ON timetables.id=timetable_entries.timetable_id

join class_timings
ON class_timings.id=timetable_entries.class_timing_id

where users.id=timetable_entries.id
```

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started: unoptimized, obviously.

```
SELECT
    timetable_entries.id AS tid,
    weekdays.weekday AS tweek,
    employees.id AS eid
    timetables.start_date as tstart
    timetables.end_date as tend
    class_timings.start_time as start
FROM
    timetable_entries,
    weekdays,
    employees,
    timetables,
    class_timings
WHERE
    timetable_entries.weekday_id = weekdays.id,
    timetable_entries.employee_id = employees.id,
    users.username = employees.employee_number,
    timetables.id = timetable_entries.timetable_id,
    class_timings.id = timetable_entries.class_timing_id,
    users.id = <PUT_ID_HERE>
```

Answer (score 0):

Rewriting a query like this is not too complex, as long as you follow the order of the `SELECT` syntax

```
-- First just add all select/addselects

SELECT timetable_entries.id as tid,
       weekdays.weekday as tweek,
       employees.id as eid,  
       timetables.start_date as tstart,
       timetables.end_date as tend,
       class_timings.start_time as start

-- then add all the JOINs

FROM timetable_entries
JOIN weekdays ON timetable_entries.weekday_id = weekdays.id
JOIN employees ON timetable_entries.employee_id = employees.id
JOIN users ON users.username = employees.employee_number
JOIN timetables ON timetables.id = timetable_entries.timetable_id
JOIN class_timings ON class_timings.id = timetable_entries.class_timing_id

-- last, add the WHERE

WHERE users.id = $this->id
```

Answer (score 0):

your code is following as :

```
SELECT(
    timetable_entries.id AS tid,
    timetables.start_date AS tstart,
    weekdays.weekday AS tweek,
    timetables.end_date AS tend,
    employees.id AS eid,
    class_timings.start_time AS START

    FROM
    timetable_entries
    JOIN weekdays timetable_entries.weekday_id=weekdays.id
    JOIN employees timetable_entries.employee_id=employees.id
    JOIN users users.username=employees.employee_number
    JOIN timetables timetables.id=timetable_entries.timetable_id
    JOIN class_timings class_timings.id=timetable_entries.class_timing_id
    WHERE users.id=?(id);
```

*Note: ? mark should be using to front end for input...*